# CustomPropertyCollection#add(key,value) method

Tags: office-js

When Creates a new custom property with String type,but in word custom properties,the field is Date type.

Code:

```
var customPros = document.properties.customProperties;
//...
customPros.add("ReportDate", "2018-04-10");
```

[Article URL](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/custompropertycollection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. If the value of the property is an ISO-compliant date of this form:

```
yyyy-mm-dd[-hh-mm-ss]
```

such as `2018-04-10`, then it will be stored as a date and the [CustomProperty.type](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/customproperty) value will be Date. (However, the hours, minutes, and seconds are ignored. It is always stored as midnight.) If you want to store it as a String, then you need to give it an noncompliant format such as `2018_04_10`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.How can I set 2018-04-10 for String field?

Comment: If there is a String field  existed in word custom properties,the default value is '2010-01-01'.When I update the value to '2018-04-20' in office-js,the field type will be changed to Date Type.

Comment: quick question: why do you want to store a Date as string? what's your scenario?

Comment: Now,The field is parsed with format 'yyyy-MM-dd' in the server, and the api can not be changed.

Comment: If you really need to save the value as a string, I would suggest that just before your code saves the string as a property, it replaces the "-" character with the "_" character. Then when your code reads the string out of the property, the first thing it does is reverse the substitution.

Comment: OK,I will try it. Thank you for your reply.